# Toggle internet very quickly

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

I really need to test how much time one program can endure with wifi connection being kicked-off and restored in a software manner.
I need to be able to quickly disable/enable network connection (or pause/recover or just lag it) with a simple keyboard shortcut.

Using the netsh is really slow and really forceful.
The laptop button to disable/enable internet is fast, but I No longer have laptop.

Another approach would be to further block networking of a process using
a key.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using DHCP open a cmd prompt window and use

```
ipconfig /release
```

then to restore its:

```
ipconfig /renew
```

This will tell the OS to release all IPv4 addresses and then the second command tells it to get another one (if you're on IPv6 just add a 6 to the end so ipconfig /release6 and ipconfig /renew6).

If you're looking to keep the time between drop and reconnect reasonably precise create a  batch file and use the timeout command like so:

```
ipconfig /release
timeout /T 10 NOBREAK
ipconfig /renew
```

This tells windows to release the IPv4 address, wait 10 seconds and then renew it - obviously change the 10 to be whatever length of disconnect you are testing.

**EDIT:**

Since my initial suggestion doesn't seem to quite meet the OP's needs, I'll add another option.

[Clumsy](https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/) is a software tool that will let you tamper with the flow of network traffic on the system, allowing you to drop packets, introduce lag, throttle the connection and generally simulate a flaky connection. Note this doesn't actually disconnect the network but rather interferes with the actual traffic on the network instead. If you're looking to test application robustness under less-than-robust network conditions this is a great tool.

Without knowing exactly what sort of behavior suits your requirements it's hard to give steps on how to use it but the [manual](https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/manual.html) is relatively straightforward and does a better job of explaining the tool and how to use it then I could manage!

Comment: Very good suggestion! Unfortunately this seems to disconnect the program immediately and is not as fast to reconnect.

Comment: It answers the question well, if I wasn't clear or detailed and as a result of that it doesn't suit my case - it is my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Edenia Happy to help! Hope Clumsy can give you the behavior you're looking for :)